# SQL subqueries to count on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, foxpro

I've table like this VB(name char(25), amount numeric(6), ret_date date):

> ```
> Name  Amount  Ret_date
> ----  ------  --------
> abc    500    2011-01-21
> def    200    2011-01-20
> ghi   1000    
> xyz    800    2011-01-22
> def    200    
> def    400    2011-02-01
> pqr   2100    2011-02-12  
> abc   3000    
> abc   4100
> xyz    700    2011-01-22
> ```

What I wanted is (count based on ret_date for distinct names: total count, return count, pending count):

```
Name    tc  rc  pc 
abc     3   1   2 
def     3   2   1 
xyz     2   2   0 
ghi     1   0   1 
pqr     1   1   0
```

I've tried the following queries, nothing worked!

```
SELECT vb.name, COUNT(*) tc, r.rc, p.pc FROM vb, ;
 (SELECT name, COUNT(*) rc FROM vb WHERE ret_date != {} group BY name) r, ;
 (SELECT name, COUNT(*) pc FROM vb WHERE ret_date = {} group BY name) p ;
 GROUP BY vb.name ORDER BY tc desc
SELECT vb.name, COUNT(*) tc, r.rc, p.pc FROM vb ;
  LEFT JOIN (select name, COUNT(*) rc FROM vb WHERE ret_date != {} group BY name) r ON r.name = vb.name ;
  LEFT JOIN (select name, COUNT(*) pc FROM vb WHERE ret_date = {} group BY name) p ON p.name = vb.name ;
  GROUP BY vb.name
SELECT vb.name, COUNT(*) tc, r.rc, p.pc FROM vb ;
  LEFT JOIN (select r.name, COUNT(*) rc FROM vb r WHERE ret_date != {} group BY name) r ON r.name = vb.name ;
  LEFT JOIN (select p.name, COUNT(*) pc FROM vb p WHERE ret_date = {} group BY name) p ON p.name = vb.name ;
  GROUP BY vb.name
```

I was able to get the count with 3 separate queries (total count, count for ret_date = {}, ret_date != {}) but can't get at the same time using a single query. Please help me get the desired output. I am new to SQL and can understand the basics but things like joins, subqueries are still difficult to understand! It would be helpful if you could explain what your query does.

Note: I'm using MS Visual Foxpro 9.0 (Windows 7). *{ }* is a notation used to express emptiness for date type in Foxpro and *!=* is not equal to operator.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT name) as uc, COUNT(*) as tc, SUM(IF(ret_date IS NULL, 0, 1)) as rc, SUM(IF(ret_date IS NOT NULL, 0, 1)) as pc
FROM vb
GROUP BY name;
```

I don't have access to Foxpro, but this works in MySQL.  Hopefully you can tweak it to suit your purposes.

Comment: That worked perfect! One thing I didn't get, the expression **COUNT(DISTINCT name) as uc** yields 1 for all the names?! Anyhow, I got what I want. One more doubt, Can't we get _pc_ value as _tc - rc_?! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: The COUNT(DISTINCT name) portion was thrown on while I was doing some testing of the query.  Sorry about that.  You can remove the name from the select, as well as the group by, and the query will give you those counts summarized over the entire table.  Otherwise you can get an accurate count of unique users by simply counting the result set from the first query.  As for pc being calculated, you could certainly do that.  I was just being explicit to provide another look at the same sort of counting trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Foxpro, however I would imagine `COUNT(*)` will give your total count, `COUNT(Ret_Date)` will give you your pending count (as it won't count null values). Then `COUNT(*) - COUNT(Ret_Date)` (tc - rc) will give your pending count. This may eliminate the need for subqueries (if VFP behaves like other DBMS when counting).

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) tc, COUNT(Ret_Name) rc,  COUNT(*) - COUNT(Ret_Name) pc
FROM VB
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: I'd check it out. Thanks for the help.